# Passing css variable as Canvas Filters

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, css-variables

I'm trying to build an image editor from scratch and I need some help.

I want to draw an image to a canvas, be able to apply different filters to it using range inputs and than download the edited image.

I started this using css variables, because I watched a tutorial talking about css variables and through it would be a good way to expand on them.

Now, I managed to control the value of a css variable using a range input, through this function:

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.controls input');
function handleUpdate() {
    const suffix = this.dataset.sizing || '';
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--${this.name}`, this.value + suffix);
}
inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('change', handleUpdate));
```

And managed to pass the css variables as strings to the canvas filter using this

```
const value = window.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--blur');
ctx.filter = 'blur(' + value + ')';
```

However, the value being passed is the one set in the css file, on root when the variable is declared, not after it is updated by the handleUpdate function.

You can take a look at the entire code in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/ClaudiuVimes/pen/wvJeJRr)

Thanks in advance for help, I feel a bit out of my depth here, and I'm making an obvious mistake.

Comment: It looks like the problem is that you are only executing the code that reads the current variable value and applies the filter, in the change handler for the image upload field. Manipulating the slider value itself does not trigger this. So you would need to explicitly choose a different image than before (selecting the same file again, won’t fire the change event) … or actually trigger applying this filter when the slider value it should be based on changes.

Comment: You don't need css variables at all here, keep it all in JS, it will be waaaay easier. Sounds like you already know how to caoncatenate a string with an input value, that's all you need.

Comment: @CBroe
Thank you for answering my question. To be honest, I'm not sure how I would trigger the filter only after the value is changed, perhaps with a promise? I'll play with it today after work and see if I can get it to work. 



and for Kaiido
I'll probably end up ditching the css variables, but they seemed so cool :)) It's my first time using native css variables and wanted to experiment with them.

Comment: Why promises? If you want to apply this after the _slider_ value has changed - well then add a change handler for _that_ input element then?

Comment: Well CSS variables are cool for CSS, for JS, not so cool no. All you need to do is to move the code you currently have in your file input onload handler in its own function, let's call it `draw()`. Then, you make your inputs handler update variables accessible to the `draw` function we just created. From these same input event handlers, you will call `draw()`. And tada!  https://codepen.io/_-0-_/pen/gOmxoPY

Comment: @Kaiido and CBroe
I def don't fully understand how promises work/when to use them.

And thanks a tone Kaiido, I got to make a functional thing out of this, even thought the way I implemented the filters is very "hacky". 

I have a question about the url() filter, since I don't fully understand what it does from the  MDN page. 

I can pass a svg filter as a canvas filter with it, and the svg can be in a separated file or inline. Correct? Is that all it can do? Or can I pass more than just a SVG filter with it? 

Also, thanks again, you seem quite proficient with the canvas.

Comment: Update code here: 
https://codepen.io/ClaudiuVimes/pen/wvJeJRr

Comment: What more would you want it to do? Yes, `url()` points to an SVG filter, it can point either to a <filter> in the current document (`#the-id-of-the-fitler-element`)  or to a <filter> in an external .svg file. And it's still very unclear why you are talking about promises here. You only deal with events, no need for promises.